# How to control fan speed with python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, fancontrol

I need to control the fan speed with python 2.7. Problem is, I can't find a way that works. I'm on ubuntu 18.04, please help!

sensors-detect output:

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion G72 Notebook PC [049D100000202710000020000] (laptop)
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 1425
# Kernel: 4.15.0-74-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz (6/37/2)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel 3400/5 Series (PCH)
Module i2c-i801 loaded successfully.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x28
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for `Nuvoton NCT7802Y'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for `Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for `ITE IT8712F'...                                No

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-B (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 4000 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Comment: are you able to control the fan with fancontrol app?  If you can get that far, then you should be able to write your own app in place of fancontrol.

Comment: I have installed fancontrol, but it has an error reading config file as it does not exist. What next?

Comment: You will also need `lm-sensors`, run `sensors-detect` and then `pwmconfig` before fan control will work properly, that is if everything goes smoothly.  If that doesn't work we will review the output of `sensors-detect`

Comment: I did all of that. But then running pwmconfig spits this out: /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Comment: Does this mean I can't control the fanspeed?

Comment: Can you post the output of `sensors-detect`.  Sometimes it can see the sensor but doesn't know what driver to use.

Comment: Okay. Done that.

Comment: I don't see anything that will get fancontrol working in the output.  What is located in `/proc/acpi`?

Comment: A file called wakeup and a folder called button.

Comment: And the fancontrol output if I run it is:  Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file

Comment: You have to run `pwm-config` first but it won't find any fans.  Either the drivers haven't been written yet or the laptop does not allow the OS to control the fan.

Comment: Yeah @rtaft, it seems you're right. It doesn't find any fans, or any pwm-capable chips. If anyone knows of a driver that might make it work, please link to it. I have a HP Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz × 4 with 7Gig memory. Thanks for your help anyway if you can't find one!